# How to change log rotate Extension..?

Tags: linux, redhat, log-files

currently my logrotate configuration adds a single number after the rotated log file:

`mylogfile.log` is rotated to `mylogfile.log.1`

I would like to change the extension to `mylogfile.log.Current date`

does anyone know a way to do this?

my log rotate code is:

```
/usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7-ND1/server/default/log/consolelog.log

{        
copytruncate
rotate 1
missingok
notifempty
}
```

Currently am renaming the rotated file with script.is there any option to change the extension of log rotate default configuration. Please help me

is there any option to change the position of extension,for example `mylogfile.log` to `mylogfile_currentdate.log`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `dateext` option at the end (after your last option notifempty).

Comment: thanks for the reply.but i need the time in the extension.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan T: You can add seconds to the extension using `dateformat`. See `man logrotate`.

Comment: is there any option to change the position of extension,for example  mylogfile.log to mylogfile_currentdate.log.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer for this queation..The above code must change as shown below

Example:

```
/usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7-ND1/server/default/log/consolelog.log {
copytruncate
rotate 1
missingok
notifempty
DATE=`date +%F`; mv /usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7-ND1/server/default/log/consolelog.log /usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7-ND1/server/default/log/consolelog_DATE.log
}
```